# apache error log file on shared hosting account

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a shared hosting account with no SSH access (only cpanel & ftp) and I have trouble viewing error logs by apache.

There is a error_log file in my home directory and I have a feeling that error logs used to go in that directory correctly when I first started working on server. Then I edited and deleted all contents in that file several times.
Now for past some days, no error message goes into that file.
Although errors from php script still go into that file correctly but not other errors like errors from CGI or bad request etc errors.

I have tried setting 777 & 640 permission on that file but nothing works.

Can anyone think of any possible thing that can be causing problem??

Thanks!

Comment: If PHP errors are getting written, it's able to write to the log.. how do you know that errors should be getting written?

Comment: I work with apache server on my local pc as well. If I access bad address on my website, that should also go into error_log. SO much info. goes into that file... but nothing on that stoopid server and my hosting guys are unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting syslog

```
/etc/init.d/syslog restart
```

Comment: Apache doesn't use syslog for logging.